# WPF: Unable to make my own GroupBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I want to make my own control, inheriting from GroupBox.

Ive followed instructions in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and that's the result of the implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GeneralUserControls
{
    public partial class MyGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        public MyGroupBox ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
        {
            base.OnPaint(pe);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it this way:

```
<Window [...]
   xmlns:guc="clr-namespace:GeneralUserControls;assembly=GeneralUserControls" >
   [...
<guc:MyGroupBox Header="Etiquette :" Width="70" Height="70">
   <Grid>
      [...]
   </Grid>
</guc:MyGroupBox>
```

It seems to not consider it as a groupbox! Here are the errors:

```
Error   1   The property 'Header' was not found in type 'MyGroupBox'.
Error   2   The type 'MyGroupBox' does not support direct content.
Error   3   Cannot add content to an object of type "MyGroupBox".
Error   9   Cannot add content to object of type 'GeneralUserControls.MyGroupBox'.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to mix WPF with WinForms. I see the namespace `using System.Windows.Forms;` You need to make a `WPF` custom control, or if you really want a `WindowsForms` control, you need to wrap it in a `WindowsFormsHost` control.

The namespace of the GroupBox in WPF is `System.Windows.Controls`. According to the link you provided, I think you read the wrong tutorial.
You could read for example this: http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html